# Erro de Syntax no MAP Angular6

Tags: angular

estou num curso de angular 4, porém estou usando o 6, ele me atnede bem, mas de vez em quando tem algumas coisas que não rolam, consegui arrumar a maioria, mas tem uma que ta me deixando louco que é o MAP no método de pesquisa. Precisaria muito avançar com isso pois meu TCC depende disto kkkk. Valeu desde já pessoal.

Topo Component (aonde fica a barra de pesquisa)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OfertasService } from '../ofertas.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Oferta } from '../shared/oferta.model';
 public pesquisa(termoDaPesquisa: string): void{
    this.ofertas = this.ofertasService.pesquisaOferta(termoDaPesquisa)
    this.ofertas.subscribe(
      (ofertas: Oferta[]) => console.log(ofertas)
  )
  }
```

oferta.service.ts (aonde fica a lógica das ofertas, aonde vou fazer a busca)

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Oferta } from './shared/oferta.model';
import { URL_API } from './app.api'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
public pesquisaOferta(termo: string): Observable<Oferta[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${URL_API}?descricao_oferta_like=${termo}`)
            .pipe(map((resposta: any) => resposta.json()))

    }
```

e o topo component html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquise por ofertas..." #termoDaPesquisa (keyup)="pesquisa(termoDaPesquisa.value)"/>
```

E vou mostrar um print da tela com o erro!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT: topo.component completo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OfertasService } from '../ofertas.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Oferta } from '../shared/oferta.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'xyz-topo',
  templateUrl: './topo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topo.component.css'],
  providers: [OfertasService]
})
export class TopoComponent implements OnInit {

  public ofertas: Observable<Oferta[]>

  constructor(private ofertasService: OfertasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public pesquisa(termoDaPesquisa: string): void{
    this.ofertas = this.ofertasService.pesquisaOferta(termoDaPesquisa)
    this.ofertas.subscribe(
      (ofertas: Oferta[]) => console.log(ofertas)
  )
  }

}
```

Comment: mostra o constructor do seu service

Comment: Desculpa a demora, cheguei em casa agora, ele está vazio
constructor(private http: Http) { }

Comment: Tem como inserir o topo.component.ts inteiro, possivelmente o erro esta ai...
Eu acho que o erro esta no seu pipe, se der certo eu posto como resposta

        .pipe(
            retry(10),
            map((response: Oferta[]) => {
                return response
            })
        )

Comment: Inserir o topo component inteiro ali, obrigado desde já pessoal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Houve alterações no método `map()`, da versão do Angular 4, para a 6. Acredito que no seu caso o problema está em que não existe mais a conversão para JSON no método `map().`

Experimente modificar o método `pesquisa()` na arquivo *ofertas.service.ts*.

```
public pesquisaOferta(termo: string): Observable<Oferta[]> {
    return this.http.get(URL_API + "?descricao_oferta_like=" + termo)
    .pipe(
        retry(10),
        map((response: Oferta[]) => {
            return response
        })
    )
}
```

Experimente também passar os três parametros na sua inscrição do observador.

```
   public pesquisa(termoDaBusca: string) : void {

    // Observavel
    this.ofertas = this.ofertasService.pesquisaOferta(termoDaBusca)

    // Observador
    this.ofertas.subscribe(
      (ofertas: Oferta[]) => {
        console.log(ofertas)
      },
      (error: string) => {
        console.log("Erro na pesquisa. Erro: " + error)
      }, () => {
        console.log("Termino do fluxo da stream")
      })
  }
```

Comment: Apenas adicionando que não existe correlação em utilizar todos os parâmetros do observable e o problema. A utilização dos mesmo é opcional e em alguns casos aconselhada. >>Good Codding!

Comment: Vou tentar! Só fiquei com uma dúvida, no curso não vi nada sobre esse retry, o que seria? Eu poderia aplicá-lo como?

Comment: Sobre o `retry()`, e um parâmetro opcional que você passa para o `pipe()`, informando a quantidade de tentativas de requisições http que você quer que ele faca ao servidor caso aconteça algum problema de conexão.

Comment: Erick meu bom, muito obrigado de verdade pela ajuda cara! To aprendendo demais com isso tudo! Fico deverás agradecido e espero passar isso pra outras pessoas também!

Comment: Erick, voltei aqui kkkk, deu certo sim, consegui recuperar os dados todos, mas literalmente estão sendo todos, não estou conseguindo filtrar como o map faria e deixar só o nome por exemplo. Estou pesquisando alguma maneira de conseguir deixar só a string de pesquisa no retorno

Comment: Esse outro problema que você esta tendo, esta relacionado ao servidor que você esta utilizando. Experimente trabalhar com esse seu servidor fora do angular.